# Angular 7 call ngOnInit method or any other method of component that is contained by component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7

I have this situation, in which I have a component called `user-table-list` that is basically a table with entries that represent some users.
The component was designed so that there is another component, called `table-list` that describes a table and its behavior for several components (and `user-table-list` is one of them). The html for `user-table-list` is in fact just like this:

```
<app-table-list #table [tableConfiguration]="usersTableConfiguration"></app-table-list>
```

while the html for `table-list` has all the design for the table, describing columns, header, etc..., while the single component describes in .ts file the configuration for its personal table, meaning which data they load to fill the table, names for the columns, and so on.

In the header there's a button to add a new entry to the table, let it be of users or clients or anything else. The event and the database retrieval are handled inside `table-list.component.ts`, that performs a different onclick action according to which type of table the event came from. Something like that:

```
createNewButtonClicked(tableType: string) {
    
    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
    dialogConfig.width = '60%';
    dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;

    switch (tableType) {
        case 'clients': {
            this.dialog.open(ClientDialogComponent, dialogConfig);
            break;
        }
        case 'projects': {
            this.dialog.open(ProjectDialogComponent, dialogConfig);
            break;
        }  
        case 'users':{
            this.dialog.open(UserDialogComponent, dialogConfig);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Inside the dialogs that are opened, a new client/project/user is added to the list. What I want is to refresh the list after closing the dialog, by calling a method of database retrieval. But this retrieval is called inside the single component, that is for example `user-table-list`. So I'm looking for a way to call the method of retrieval and refresh the list of `user-table-list` from the outside, without having to refresh the page from the browser. The problem is that I can't achieve that, not in the dialog component nor the table-list component. I've tried importing the component in the constructor and calling the method, both in dialog and table-list component, but it gives a warning for a circular reference and does nothing. Same if I create an external service to call the method, because there is always a circular reference.
I'm out of alternatives; how can this be done?
Unfortunately I can't alter the application design.

Comment: is the list that you need to refresh inside of the table-list component (the same class that has that createNewButtonClicked method?

Comment: Nope, is the other component, that is user-table-list (or whatever it is that is not just table-list)

Comment: updated answer to reflect this

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your are use a material dialog the dialogs give you an observable you can watch for to see when the dialog is closed. if you set it to a variable you can watch for when it is closed, for instance:

```
createNewButtonClicked(tableType: string) {
    // your existing logic
    // ... 
    const dialog = this.dialog.open(ClientDialogComponent, dialogConfig);
    // example dialog .afterClosed
    dialog.afterClosed().subscribe(closeResult => {
        // update from database after dialog is closed
    });
}
```

You could use an Output property to tell parent components that something happened inside of the child. Inside of the subscribe function (where I put a comment to update database) is where you would want to emit that the dialog was closed. Your code for list could look something like this:
    @Output() dialogClosed = new EventEmitter();

```
createNewButtonClicked(tableType: string) {
    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
    dialogConfig.width = '60%';
    dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;
    let dialog;
    switch (tableType) {
        case 'clients': {
            dialog = this.dialog.open(ClientDialogComponent, dialogConfig);
            break;
        }
        case 'projects': {
            dialog = this.dialog.open(ProjectDialogComponent, dialogConfig);
            break;
        }  
        case 'users':{
            dialog = this.dialog.open(UserDialogComponent, dialogConfig);
            break;
        }
    }
    // check to see if dialog was opened
    if (!!dialog) {
        dialog.afterClosed().subscribe(closeResult => {
            // emit that dialog was closed
            this.dialogClosed.next();
        });
    }
}
```

Then in your user-table component watch for the event to be emitted:

```
<app-table-list (dialogClosed)="onDialogClosed($event)"></app-table-list>
```

And finally your user tables ts. Note that I am not calling ngOnInit when the dialog is closed as the purprose of ngOnInit is to initialize. So extract the database logic inside of ngOnInit into another method and call this method to update data when the dialog is closed as well:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.getData();
}

onDialogClose() {
    this.getData();
}

private getData() {
  // make database calls here and update data from response
}
```

You should only use ngOnInit to initialize the view as you may be setting some defaults in here that you do not want to reset, so it is recommended to not call ngOnInit again later in the pages life cycle

Answer (score 0):

You must issue an event from the submit button that is inside the Dialog. That is, capture the click event of the Dialog and from table-list notify the parent components that clicked.

Something like that:

**table-list.component.ts**

```
@Output() clickedOkDialog = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

onClickOkDialog() {
  this.clickedOkDialog.emit(true);
}
```

Then you can capture the event in user-table-list

**In your user-table-list.component.html**

```
<app-table-list (clickedOkDialog)="onClickOkDialog($event)" #table [tableConfiguration]="usersTableConfiguration"></app-table-list>
```

In your user-table-list.component.ts

```
onClickOkDialog(event) {
   // update from database after dialog is closed
}
```